# Graphic going to next page regardless of what I do

Tags: floats, titles

I'm brand new to LaTeX, it's required for my Data Science class and I'm working on my first assignment.  No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the graphic to go to the top of the first page.  It keeps going to the 2nd page, and even the stuff I type after the graphic goes to the first page while the graphic stays on the 2nd..

The assignment specifies that the graphic needs to be at the top of the page, but I can't get it to align accordingly.  I just need help on this one aspect, I have the rest of it completed already.

Thanks

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{CDS 302 Assignment 1}
\author{Michael Martin}

\date{30 January 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/Vader.jpg}
    \caption{Darth Vader}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction}

This is an introduction.  The first rule of science to to "not blow up the lab."

\section{Experiments}

I did the experiment.  The lab blew up.

\subsection{Future work}

They asked me to never repeat that experiment again.  I should have read Section \ref{introduction}.


\section{Tables}
\label{tables}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Location & Color & Target \\
    \hline
    \hline
    (1,2) & \textcolor{red}{red} & 1 \\
    (3,4) & \textcolor{green}{green} & 0 \\
    (2,3) & \textcolor{blue}{blue} & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

The  first  column  in  Table  1  contains  pixel  locations,  and  the  second  col-umn contains the associated color.  Figure 1 shows Darth Vader.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

By default `\maketitle` sets the maximum number of top floats in the first page to 0 so the title comes first, but if you must over-ride that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{CDS 302 Assignment 1}
\author{Michael Martin}

\date{30 January 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\global\csname @topnum\endcsname=1

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image.jpg}
    \caption{Darth Vader}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction}

This is an introduction.  The first rule of science to to "not blow up the lab."

\section{Experiments}

I did the experiment.  The lab blew up.

\subsection{Future work}

They asked me to never repeat that experiment again.  I should have read Section \ref{introduction}.


\section{Tables}
\label{tables}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Location & Color & Target \\
    \hline
    \hline
    (1,2) & \textcolor{red}{red} & 1 \\
    (3,4) & \textcolor{green}{green} & 0 \\
    (2,3) & \textcolor{blue}{blue} & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

The first column in Table 1 contains pixel locations, and the second
col-umn contains the associated color.  Figure 1 shows Darth Vader.


\end{document}
```